# Can I use joomla!/wordpress to build my website?

Tags: wordpress, joomla

Basically I want to build a website based on some original content,
the content have some attributes like: 
category, event time, location, people involved, summary, details, reports...
and I want user to be able to search based on different attributes
e.g. search by people's name, or search by categories or location

And also I want to add a subscription or membership system, so that users can get (for example) detailed report after they pay the membership, they can also pay a little to look at a particular event's content.

Can I archive those simply by using joomla!/wordpress or do I have to build the site from scratch using more complex frameworks like ruby on rails/django?

Thanks

Comment: You can build a website with a set of tinkertoys and a used piece of chewing gum. The question is if it's worth your time working around the limitations of your tools. WP is quite flexible,but also a serious pain to work with if your site's not "mostly" a blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience (which isn't totally up-to-date on either tool; I'm currently working with a Joomla1.5 site, and have used Wordpress in the past), Wordpress will be the slightly easier of the two - it makes 'custom content' easier to define and create. Having said that, unless you actually *need* a full-blown CMS (e.g. you need to support many users who cannot learn HTML), and if you have good PHP/ruby/etc. knowledge, you could well be better off building a bespoke system.

It comes down to a) how flexible you want your site to be b) how 'unique' your requirements are c) how much time you have on your hands. If you do 'roll your own', make sure you use existing libraries (for things like captcha, spam-handling, email sending) wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can build a website like that with Joomla (maybe with Wp too but I'm not sure). There are a lot of good extensions (sometimes you have to pay for the good ones) to manage events, communities and memberships.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at expression engine because:

1. It has most of the things you require straight out of the box (you'd have to extend joomla and WP):

http://expressionengine.com/overview/features

1. It's built on the Codeigniter framework which is excellent.